# Ajax GET requests not working on windows server 2016 but are working on IIS 10

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, iis, asp.net-core

I could really do with some help. I have two functions for populating the DOM with ajax requests and I have one function to periodically update the loaded DOM.

I have the following **Ajax GET** requests that are working on my local machine when running from visual studio and when hosted on IIS v10 on my local machine. **The Problem: ** when I deploy this application to my test server that is Windows Server 2016 with the following IIS version: [Test server IIS version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpcj5.png)

The application and ajax requests work perfectly on my local machine which is a windows 10 machine that has an IIS version of: [Windows 10 michine IIS version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cm1L.png)

This is a **.NET core 2.1** backend application, using Razor pages for the views and I am trying to populate the  tags with html based on the responses from my ajax calls and periodically update some values within the populated HTML. Is there something I am missing with regard to the server IIS setup, do I need a special configuration in my application or have I missed a parameter or something in my AJAX? I have added alerts for testing to know if I have entered my AJAX when viewing in the browser. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

```js
'use strict';

$(function getType1DashboardItems() {
    alert("Entered getType1DashboardItems ")

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        url: 'api/GetQuantumDashboardItemsAsync/Type1',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache: false,
        success: function success(data) {
            alert("Successfully called 'api/GetQuantumDashboardItemsAsync/Type1' in getType1DashboardItems ")
            $.each(data.areas, function (i, area) {
                //HTML for dashboard areas
                var areaHtml = '<div id="dashboardArea-' + area.guid + '" class="area-card card col-sm-3 p-2"> ' +
                    '<div class="dashboard-heading"><strong id="areaHeading" class="area-heading">' + area.title + '</strong></div><hr class="heading-underline"/>' +
                    '<div id="areaDataSources-' + area.guid + '" class="card data-source-card"></div>';
                $('#Type1Areas').append(areaHtml);

                //dashboardItems array
                var dashboardItems = area.dashboardItems;
                getDataSources(area, dashboardItems);
            });
        },
        complete: function complete() {
            refreshDashboardItems("Type1");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, data) {
            console.log('xhr: ' + xhr);
            console.log('textStatus: ' + textStatus);
            console.log('data: ' + data);
        }
    });
});

$(function getType2DashboardItems() {
    alert("Entered getType2DashboardItems ")

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        url: 'api/GetQuantumDashboardItemsAsync/Type2',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache: false,
        success: function success(data) {
            alert("Entered getType1DashboardItems ")

            $.each(data.areas, function (i, area) {
                //HTML for dashboard areas
                var areaHtml = '<div id="dashboardArea-' + area.guid + '" class="area-card card col-sm-3 p-2">' +
                    '<div class="dashboard-heading"><strong id="areaHeading" class="area-heading">' + area.title + '</strong></div><hr class="heading-underline"/>' +
                    '<div id="areaDataSources-' + area.guid + '" class="card data-source-card"></div>';
                $('#Type2Areas').append(areaHtml);

                //dashboardItems array
                var dashboardItems = area.dashboardItems;
                getDataSources(area, dashboardItems);
            });
        }, complete: function complete() {
            refreshDashboardItems("Type2");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, data) {
            console.log('xhr: ' + xhr);
            console.log('textStatus: ' + textStatus);
            console.log('data: ' + data);
        }
    });
});

function refreshDashboardItems(dashboard) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        url: 'api/GetQuantumDashboardItemsAsync/' + dashboard,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache: false,
        success: function success(dashboard) {
            alert("Successfully called 'refreshDashboardItems for "+ dashboard.toString())

            var dashboardTitle = dashboard.title;
            $.each(dashboard.areas, function (i, area) {

                var highestPriorityColour = ""
                var monitorTargetPanelHeader = document.getElementById(dashboardTitle + "DropdownPanel");

                $.each(area.dashboardItems, function (i, dashboardItem) {
                    var date = moment(dashboardItem.dataProviderHealth.dateLastAccessed).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');

                    var dataSourceCountContainer = document.getElementById("data-source-count-" + dashboardItem.guid);
                    var dataSourcePartsContainer = document.getElementById("listOfParts-" + dashboardItem.guid);
                    var dataSourceLastAccessed = document.getElementById("dataSourceLastAccessed-" + dashboardItem.guid);


                    //DataSource parts are added to the parts list
                    var partsList = "";
                    $.each(dashboardItem.parts, function (i, part) {
                        var newPart = "<li class='part'>" + part.serialNumber + "</li>";
                        partsList += newPart;
                    });

                    dataSourceCountContainer.innerHTML = dashboardItem.count + " Files Pending";
                    dataSourcePartsContainer.innerHTML = partsList;
                    dataSourceLastAccessed.innerHTML = date;

                    var statusColour = dashboardItem.statusColour.toLowerCase()

                    if (statusColour == "red") {
                        highestPriorityColour = "red"
                    }
                    else if (statusColour == "orange" && highestPriorityColour != "red") {
                        highestPriorityColour = "orange"
                    }
                });
                if (highestPriorityColour != "") {
                    $(monitorTargetPanelHeader).removeClass(monitorTargetPanelHeader.className).addClass("k-link panel-bar-header-" + highestPriorityColour);
                }
                else {
                    $(monitorTargetPanelHeader).removeClass("panel-bar-header-red");
                    $(monitorTargetPanelHeader).removeClass("panel-bar-header-orange");
                    $(monitorTargetPanelHeader).addClass("k-link k-header");
                }
            });
        },
        complete: function complete() {
            setTimeout($.proxy(refreshDashboardItems, this, dashboard), 10000);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, data) {
            console.log('xhr: ' + xhr);
            console.log('textStatus: ' + textStatus);
            console.log('data: ' + data);
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="panels">
    <ul id="panelbar">
        <li id="Type2DashboardList" class="area k-state-active">
            <span id="Type2DropdownPanel" class="k-link k-state-selected">Type2</span>
            <div id="PanelBarContents" class="panel-bar-contents">
                <ul id="Type2Areas" class="area-row row"></ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="Type1DashboardList" class="area">
            <span id="Type1DropdownPanel" class="k-link">Type1</span>
            <div id="PanelBarContents" class="panel-bar-contents">
                <ul id="Type1Areas" class="area-row row"></ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** added images of errors from dev tools.
[This is the error I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng1YK.png)

[and this one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb8ry.png)

[Here is the network headers for the request.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5uvX.png) - It is a 200 repsonse which is what confuses me.

Comment: have you used browser dev tools to look for script errors or 404s? maybe your scripts are not published.

Comment: *"not working"* doesn't tell us very much. Are requests being made? Any output in success or error handler? Need to narrow this down a bit

Comment: @charlietfl I have added images of the erros that I am seeing in dev tools on the server. Ignore the fact that the request url's are named differently. That is due to me simplifying the naming in the initial post.

Comment: @atmalone Could you please check again your back-end code? I think there would be a JSON serialization error, due to circular reference in your response model.